# Relacionamento 1:1 com classe abstrata no EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, modelo-relacional

Tudo bem pessoal?

estou com o seguinte problema: Eu tenho duas classes **Person** e **Property** que podem possuir um endereço (**Address**), porém a classe **Person** pode ter *0:N* **Address** e a **Property** *0:1*. Sabendo disso transformei a classe **Address** em ***abstrata*** e criei outras duas classes que herdam os atributos dela, conforme print abaixo.

[image: Modelagem]

Após essa modelagem, criei as classes **Address**, **AddressPerson** e **AddressProperty** da seguinte maneira:

```
[Table("ADDRESSES")]
public abstract class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(6)]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Neighborhood { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Complement { get; set; }

    public StatusAddressEnum.StatusAddress Status { get; set; }
    public KindAddressEnum.KindAddress KindAddress { get; set; }
}

[Table("ADDRESSES_PERSONS")]
public class AddressPerson : Address
{
    public AddressPerson()
    {
        KindAddress = KindAddressEnum.KindAddress.PERSON;
    }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

[Table("ADDRESS_PROPERTIES")]
public class AddressProperty : Address
{
    public AddressProperty()
    {
        KindAddress = KindAddressEnum.KindAddress.PROPERTY;
    }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Property")]
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Property Property { get; set; }
}
```

Ao tentar criar uma migration tenho o seguinte erro: AddressProperty_Property_Source: : *Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'AddressProperty_Property_Source' in relationship 'AddressProperty_Property'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.*

Se eu retirar o atributo *AddressId* da classe **Address** e passar para a **AddressPerson**, o EF reclama que a classe **Address** não possui uma *Key*. Qual seria a forma correta para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Eu acho que o relacionamento é muitos para muitos! ??? tipo `Person` e `Address` gera um tabela `PersonAddress` na mesma lógica com `Property`, bom pelo menos eu acho ... !!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic está correta a modelagem, um endereço(Address) pertence a somente uma pessoa (Person) ou a uma propriedade(Property).